# kotlin, how to check if a index is in range

Tags: kotlin

Having a case that a map is passed in with data like

```
Map<Pair<Int, Int>), String>

Pair<Int, Int>) // zero based star index, inclusive end index
to
displayString
```

when doing the process, need to pick up proper displayString for current position, like

```
var index = 0
for (data in dataList) {
   /*
   if the current index is within one of the pair<int, int> 
   then use the mapped displayString
   */
   index++
}
```

what is best way to do in kotlin?

Comment: Are you asking how to check is `index` is within the range of `data.first` and `data.second` ?

Comment: yes, put kinda of get from map by key

Comment: Your first code block is kind of incomprehensible. Maybe you can clarify your question some. What is `dataList`? If it's a `Map`, it doesn't make sense to iterate it with an index because the order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but possibly something like this:

```
var index = 0
for (data in dataList) {
   /*
   if the current index is within one of the pair<int, int> 
   then use the mapped displayString
   */
   val currentPair = data.key
   if ((currentPair.first .. currentPair.second).contains(index)) {
       // do something
   }

   index++
}
```

Though if you meant you wanted a getter to get the first pair from the map which contains an int the perhaps you wanted something like this:

```
fun getByIndex(dataList: Map<Pair<Int,Int>, String>, index: Int): String? {
   return dataList.firstOrNull { 
       (it.key.first .. it.key.second).contains(index) 
   } 
}
```

Use `until` instead of `..` to have exclusive end index

Comment: In practice, I wouldn't use a `Pair`, as that doesn't tell you very much about the meaning of the two numbers.  You could define a simple `Range` class, and add a `contains()` method…  But JetBrains have already done it for us: see [kotlin.ranges.IntRange](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/index.html), which does all that and more.  Then you can just do `if (myValue in theRange)`.

Comment: @gidds I just used the data structure he had in the question

Comment: Of course — I wasn't criticising, just adding some background info for posterity!

Comment: To add a little more information what Kotlin functions are used...
The example above uses an `IntRange`
It can be created like 
```IntRange(500, 599).contains(value)```
or as shown 
`(500 .. 599).contains(value)`